# "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!", yet a mysqld process is running on port 3306?

Tags: mysql

I notice that a `mysqld` process is running on port 3306:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :3306
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  63026 _mysql   19u  IPv6 0x67fbb37dac8af9c7      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

I would like to stop this process. However, if I try `mysql.server stop`, I get the following error:

```
$ mysql.server stop
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

I'm on MacOS, by the way. Using `sudo`, I'm able to find a `.pid` file:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/mysql
$ sudo find . -name '*pid'
./data/mysqld.local.pid
```

However, I'm not sure whether it's the one expected by the `mysql.server stop` command.

The problem I'm ultimately trying to solve is that when I try the `mysql` command, I get the following error:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kurtpeek'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm trying to follow the password reset instructions at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, but I can't seem to get past the first step, which is to stop the MySQL server. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a high-level explanation of this problem at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255671/error-mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found. The server has to be stopped using the MySQL Preferences Pane:

[image]

Now the `sudo lsof -i :3306` command doesn't show any processes running.